# Vega visualization custom html

Tags: data-visualization, vega, vega-lite

Is there a way to include custom HTML on the visualization of a vega object (https://vega.github.io/vega/) ?

In certain scenarios we'd need to embed custom html together with the visual chart/graph.

Answer (score 0):

Not right now because Vega supports both Canvas and SVG renders as well as rendering to images and so embedding HTML won't be possible in general. We might add support for some kind of "foreign embedded object" in the future but there are no concrete plans.